# calculate percentage of a variable conditional on two other variables in r

Tags: r

I am very new to r and want to calculate the percentage of a variable based on two other variables. A simplified version of my data is:

```
choice g score
1 M .10
1 M .20
1 F .15
1 F .15
1 M .20
2 M .05
2 M .05
2 M .15
2 F .20
```

The result I am looking for is:

```
choice score %g(M) %g(F)
1 .10 .333 0
1 .15 0 1
1 .20 .667
2 .05 .667 0
2 .15 .333 0 
2 .20 0 1
```

I hope this is clear. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: *"I hope this is clear"* No sorry, this is not clear to me. For `choice = 1` and `score = 0.10` why is the percentage of `M` `0.333`? Can you elaborate on the rules for calculating the percentages. What happens if you have duplicate rows (e.g. for `choice = 1`, `g = F` and `score = 0.15`)?

Comment: Distinguishing between proportions that add to 1 and percentages that add to 100  would (have) help(ed) here. (Out of context a percentage of 0.333 can surely only mean 0.333%.)

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the `tidyverse` package. The key is to count the row number tiwce for different group columns, calcualte the percentage, and then spread the data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(choice, g) %>%
  add_count() %>%
  group_by(choice, g, score) %>%
  add_count() %>%
  mutate(Percentage = nn/n) %>%
  select(-n, -nn) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  spread(g, Percentage, fill = 0) %>%
  select(choice, score, `%g(M)` = M, `%g(F)` = F) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   choice score `%g(M)` `%g(F)`
#    <int> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1      1  0.1    0.333       0
# 2      1  0.15   0           1
# 3      1  0.2    0.667       0
# 4      2  0.05   0.667       0
# 5      2  0.15   0.333       0
# 6      2  0.2    0           1
```

Or the following, which is more concise than my previous solution.

```
dat2 <- dat %>%
  count(choice, g, score) %>%
  group_by(choice, g) %>%
  mutate(Percentage = n/sum(n)) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  spread(g, Percentage, fill = 0) %>%
  select(choice, score, `%g(M)` = M, `%g(F)` = F) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#    choice score `%g(M)` `%g(F)`
#    <int> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1      1  0.1    0.333       0
# 2      1  0.15   0           1
# 3      1  0.2    0.667       0
# 4      2  0.05   0.667       0
# 5      2  0.15   0.333       0
# 6      2  0.2    0           1
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "choice g score
1 M .10
                  1 M .20
                  1 F .15
                  1 F .15
                  1 M .20
                  2 M .05
                  2 M .05
                  2 M .15
                  2 F .20",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Wow, well done for reverse-engineering the rules. Poor question. Excellent answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `data.table`. Basically, OP is looking for something like a contingency table in percentage terms. The `table` function will come in useful here:

```
#convert into a factor
dat[, g := as.factor(g)]

#count number of M/F for each choice and g
dat[, nMF := .N, by=.(choice, g)]

#tabulate the observations and divide by number of M/F
dat[, as.list(table(g) / nMF), by=.(choice, score)]
```

output:

```
   choice score F         M
1:      1  0.10 0 0.3333333
2:      1  0.20 0 0.6666667
3:      1  0.15 1 0.0000000
4:      2  0.05 0 0.6666667
5:      2  0.15 0 0.3333333
6:      2  0.20 1 0.0000000
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("choice g score
1 M .10
1 M .20
1 F .15
1 F .15
1 M .20
2 M .05
2 M .05
2 M .15
2 F .20")
```